# How to add resultset rows to a result array as indexed subarrays?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, row, resultset

I have a mysqli resultset with two columns of data and several rows.  I want to store each row of the resultset as an indexed subarray in my result array (specifically in `$rows['data']`).

This is my current code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_UTC,Total_watts FROM combined_readings");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Total_watts';
while ($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $tmp['Energy_UTC'];
    $rows['data'][] = $tmp['Total_watts'];
}
```

This results in an array that looks like this:

```
{"name":"Total_watts","data":[1519334969,259,1519335149,246,1519335329,589,1519335509,589,1519335689,341,1519335869,341,1519336050,523,1519336230,662,1519336410,662,1519336590,469]}
```

But I need the result to be an array that looks like this:

```
{"name":"Total_watts","data":[1519334969,259],[1519335149,246],[1519335329,589],[1519335509,589],[1519335689,341],[1519335869,341],[1519336050,523],[1519336230,662],[1519336410,662],[1519336590,469]}
```

Can someone suggest a change in the PHP while loop to produce this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust your syntax to place the elements in the same subarray.

```
while($tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $rows['data'][] = [$tmp['Energy_UTC'],$tmp['Total_watts']];
}
```

p.s. Additionally, you could use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` since you are only accessing the associative keys.  Or even better, use `mysqli_fetch_row()` and assign the row to your result array.

All baked, it could look like this:

```
if(!$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Energy_UTC,Total_watts FROM combined_readings")){
    // handle the query error
}else{
    $rows=['name'=>'Total_watts'];
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $rows['data'][]=$row;  // this will store subarrays like: [1519334969,259]
    }
}
```